# Determining customary distance unit from ISO 3166 country code

Tags: locale, iso-3166

[ISO 3166](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1_alpha-2) defines country codes such as **GB**, **US**, **FR** or **RU**.

I would like a reasonably definitive association from these country codes to the customary unit of measure for distances between places in those countries.

Specifically on iOS and OS X, the country code can be retrieved from [`NSLocale`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/classes/NSLocale_Class/Reference/Reference.html):

```
[[NSLocale currentLocale] objectForKey: NSLocaleCountryCode];
```

`NSLocale` also provides a way to see if a country uses metric or non metric units:

```
const bool useMetric = [[[NSLocale currentLocale] objectForKey: NSLocaleUsesMetricSystem] boolValue];
```

However, this is not sufficient. For example, in Great Britain (**GB**) the metric system is widely used, but distances between places continue to be officially measured in miles rather than kilometres.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I also faced this problem :-)

**Countries which uses Metric system but still use miles** :--
1. GB is only exception which still uses miles instead of metric. 
Note: Canada also stared using KMs for road transport. Although, Canada still follows miles for train and horse transport

**Countries which do not uses Metric System**
Liberia, Myanmar and United States of America.
Note: Myanmar (Formerly Burma) is planning to move to metric system. Currently, Myanmar uses its own system different from imperial and metric.

**In my app**, i check whether country uses imperial or metric.

if (metric) then assign kms for all countries except britan

if (imperial) then assign miles for all countries except Burma

if burma then assign burma unit

if britan then assign miles

Comment: :-) Glad to hear: that's about the option I took in the end too. It's also good to know, as a Britain, that we still win at being notably more insane than any other nation on Earth with the possible exceptions of Canada and Burma.

Comment: I'll add an edit to your answer to give the code I'm using. It may get rejected by the moderators. Either way – feel free to add it or not.

Answer (score 0):

A chart showing [countries using miles per hour for road speeds](http://chartsbin.com/view/5261) is available. It cites Wikipedia's articles on [miles per hour](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miles_per_hour) as its source, which has the following to say:

> These include roads in the United Kingdom,[1] the United States,[2] and UK and US territories; American Samoa,[3] the Bahamas,[4] Belize,[5] British Virgin Islands,[6] the Cayman Islands,[7] Dominica,[8] the Falkland Islands,[9] Grenada,[10] Guam,[11] Burma,[12] The N. Mariana Islands,[13] Samoa,[14] St. Lucia,[15] St. Vincent & The Grenadines,[16] St. Helena,[17] St. Kitts & Nevis,[18] Turks & Caicos Islands,[19] the U.S. Virgin Islands,[20][21] Antigua & Barbuda (although km are used for distance),[22] and Puerto Rico (same as former).[22]

I don't see a way to download this as data keyed from ISO3166 country code, but it's not a huge task to compile one.

---

I'll leave this answer unaccepted in case a better suggestion is available.

Answer (score -1):

Officially, road distances in the UK are in kilometres, but road signs are in miles. Confusing? Yes! When a road engineer get aplan of a road, everythign is in kiolometres, government statistics are in kilometres, but road signs and car odometers are in miles.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Driver_location_sign for more info.

Comment: This doesn't exactly solve the question the OP asked.